# Mine blocks to specified address in regtest mode

Tags: mining-reward, regtest, immature-coins

I am running the ruimarinho/bitcoin-core docker image and trying to understand why the block reward is going to the wrong btc address.

I have the following scenario:

```bash
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest createwallet mywallet
{
  "name": "mywallet",
  "warning": ""
}
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest createwallet minerwallet
{
  "name": "minerwallet",
  "warning": ""
}

$ ADDR=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=mywallet getnewaddress mywallet legacy) 
$ MINER_ADDR=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=minerwallet getnewaddress minerwallet legacy)

$ echo $ADDR $MINER_ADDR
muHrQQbYfhzVH4GCTZh4ZnKZvWBHVcqg66 mz3QWUnL94q2RdRxFtPq747SngoBu5uQMi

$ bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress 101 $ADDR # generate 100 blocks which will add bitcoin to 'mywallet'

$ TXID=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=mywallet sendtoaddress) "mtuFXC3oACRqVMMqN32L5VG7ZCbaE7aZxi" 10 # send 10 btc to random addr

$ bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=minerwallet generateblock $MINER_ADDR "[\"$TXID\"]" # mine the transaction

$ bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=mywallet getbalance
89.99977500
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=minerwallet getbalance
0.00000000
```

Why is the minerwallet not getting the block reward of 50 btc? I was expecting this output:

```bash
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=mywallet getbalance
39.999775
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=minerwallet getbalance
50.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate a new block, its corresponding block reward needs to mature first for 100 blocks until it is spendable. In your case, it should show up as immature if you run `getbalances` (note the extra `s`).

```
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=minerwallet getbalances
> {
    "mine": {
    "trusted": 0.00000000,
    "untrusted_pending": 0.00000000,
    "immature": 50.00000000
  },
...
```

This also explains why the balance of your "mywallet" shows as 89.99977500: After having received the block reward of 101 blocks, the first block reward is mature (50 BTC). You then subtract the 10 BTC you sent to your other address, and a small transaction fee. After that, you generate another block to the `$MINER_ADDR`, which makes the second block reward for "mywallet" mature, adding another 50 BTC to the wallet's balance.